# Mapbox API PUT Datasets Feature return "Provide a single Feature to insert"

Tags: python, python-requests, mapbox, mapbox-marker, grequests

I am trying to add a feature to the Dataset via Mapbox API using Python. I'm following this instruction https://docs.mapbox.com/api/maps/#update-a-dataset but keep getting this error:

```
{'message': 'Provide a single Feature to insert'}
```

The code looks like this:

```
rs = []
dictionary = {
"id":1,
"type":"Feature",
"properties":{},
"geometry":{"coordinates":[-83.750246, 42.269375],"type":"Point"}}
url = "https://api.mapbox.com/datasets/v1/voratima/"+dataset+"/features/1?access_token="+access_token
rs.append(grequests.put(url, data=dictionary, hooks = {'response' : do_something}))
grequests.map(rs, exception_handler=exception_handler)
```

I've tried the following but none of them work:

- using `requests` instead of `grequests`
- wrapping the dictionary with `json.dumps()`
- changing the put parameter from `data=dictionary` to `json=dictionary`
- Making sure the `id` for both data and URL are set to `1`.

Postman of the exact same request does not have the error. What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

Given a dataset with dataset ID `dataset` exists, your request body looks ok.
Please add the header

```
headers = {'Content-type': 'application/json'}
```

Also can you check if you meet these specs:

> This should be one individual GeoJSON feature, not a GeoJSON
> FeatureCollection. If the GeoJSON feature has a top-level id property,
> it must match the feature_id you use in the URL endpoint.

Comment: The feature_id is 1 for both. And the dictionary is a GeoJSON feature. Adding the header gives me a different error.

<Response [400]> {'message': 'Unexpected token i'}

Comment: The id in the dictionary has to be a string.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out I forgot the header. Thanks to Mortiz for pointing that out. After the update I got

```
<Response [400]> {'message': 'Unexpected token i'}
```

That's because I need to wrap the dictionary inside `json.dumps()`. Then the error became

```
<Response [422]> {'message': 'Request URI does not match feature id'}
```

That's because the `id` in the dictionary has to be a string i.e. `"id":"1"` not `"id":1`. Here's the code that works:

```
rs = []
dictionary = {
    "id":"1",
    "type":"Feature",
    "properties":{},
    "geometry":{"coordinates":[-83.750246, 42.269375],"type":"Point"}}
headers = {'Content-type': 'application/json'} 
url = "https://api.mapbox.com/datasets/v1/voratima/"+dataset+"/features/1?access_token="+access_token
rs.append(grequests.put(url, data=json.dumps(dictionary), headers=headers, hooks = {'response' : do_something}))
grequests.map(rs, exception_handler=exception_handler)
```